# ggplot2 Probability Histogram or Polygon to compare distributions

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, polygon

I'm trying to compare the first digit distributions of different datasets, but I cannot find any way (or guide) to demonstrate them with ggplot2. Everybody uses examples with "raw data" and not the probabilities. Here are some of my data:

This is the desired first digit distribution (my benchmark):

```
0.30103000 0.17609126 0.12493874 0.09691001 0.07918125 0.06694679 0.05799195 0.05115252 0.04575749
```

This is the first digit distribution of two datasets:

```
0.37101911 0.17515924 0.08917197 0.08121019 0.06210191 0.06050955 0.07484076 0.03662420 0.04936306
0.524419536 0.253002402 0.092073659 0.032826261 0.025620496 0.019215372 0.008807046 0.012009608 0.032025620
```

The probabilities above correspond to the probability to have as first digit 1, 2,..., 9.

Below there is a plot made by the publisher of the package I use to find the above probabilities:

[1st Dataset first-digit Distribution (the red line is my "benchmark")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dufj.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have pre-calculated probabilities, you can plot them with `geom_line`.

```
dat = read.table(text="0.30103000 0.17609126 0.12493874 0.09691001 0.07918125 0.06694679 0.05799195 0.05115252 0.04575749

                 0.37101911 0.17515924 0.08917197 0.08121019 0.06210191 0.06050955 0.07484076 0.03662420 0.04936306
                 0.524419536 0.253002402 0.092073659 0.032826261 0.025620496 0.019215372 0.008807046 0.012009608 0.032025620", header=FALSE)
dat = setNames(as.data.frame(t(dat)), c("Reference", "D1","D2"))
dat$digits = 1:9

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

ggplot(melt(dat, id.var="digits"), aes(digits, value, colour=variable)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(size=variable)) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:9) +
  scale_size_manual(values=c(1.2,0.5,0.5)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("black",hcl(c(15,195),100,65))) +
  labs(x="First Digit", y="Probability", colour="", size="")
```

[image]